# SharePoint Date Flow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column

I have a list that has a CurrentDate column.

With no more SharePoint Designer, where someone once helped me build code for this; as I'm really not very good at any of this to begin with), how can I create a process that triggers -every 24 hrs- an update to the CurrentDate column in my list?

Is there a way to automatically force an update of a list Current Date column, thus keeping 'date-based' compliance data in the rest of the list current?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer 2013 can be used with newer versions of SharePoint (2016/2019/Online). You can therefore create SharePoint 2013 workflows (if this is how you achieved your requirement previously).

Comment: Yeah, I don't code. That's why I had someone help me. 

So, the fact that I'm familiar with SP Designer doesn't really help me. Just makes me dangerous.

Know a coder that can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to make a current date column always displays today's date, have a try with a calculated column. As a workaround you can use a formula like `=TEXT(NOW(),"mm-dd-yyyy")` to have the current date.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, indeed. That did it! :-)

Comment: @Curtis Glad to be help. You can mark the reply as answer if it solves your problem